# Adding Camera Intent to AlarmManager

Tags: android-studio

I want to setup AlarmManager that it will take a picture every hour.

So many standard get started AlarmManager examples that usually setup a BroadcastReceiver such as

```
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm went off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

}

Is there a way to add the camera intent inside the BroadcastReciever. For instance is won't take the command startActivityForResult()

Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);